# Firebase error handling for account creation and login - Pyrebase

Tags: python, error-handling, firebase-authentication, pyrebase

I'm trying to handle for errors when users are signing up or logging in to my app. The first error I'm trying to handle for is when a user tries to create an account with an email that already exists in the database. I get the following `HTTPError`:

```
 requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=] {
   "error": {
     "code": 400,
     "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS",
     "errors": [
       {
         "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS",
         "domain": "global",
         "reason": "invalid"
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

I want to access the `"message": "EMAIL_EXISTS"` value in the below but I'm not sure how to do it. I've added the below code but that produces the following error:

```
     error_message = error["error"]["message"]
 TypeError: 'HTTPError' object is not subscriptable
```

```
import requests
import pyrebase

class CreateAccount():

    def create_account(self):

        try:
            auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(self.email, self.password)

        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error:
            print(error)
            error_message = error["error"]["message"]
            print(error_message)
```

Answer (score 6):

After much searching I've found an answer to this problem:

```
        except requests.HTTPError as e:
            error_json = e.args[1]
            error = json.loads(error_json)['error']['message']
            if error == "EMAIL_EXISTS":
                print("Email already exists")
```

Comment: Im not sure if youll see this this late but i tried adding this to my code and got the error "json" is not defined. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: have you imported json?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the code you provided in comment which I couldn't make to work. Maybe a version issue of requests module or something else.

However, the code below works in my case:

```
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
  error_json = e.args[1]
  error = json.loads(error_json)['error']['message']
  if error == "EMAIL_EXISTS":
      print("Email already exists")
```

Yeah, `requests.exceptions.HTTPError` instead of `requests.HTTPError`.